# Print Entity Reference Value from Entity Meta Wrapper

Tags: 7, entities

I have this code to get entity meta wrapper and print text fields. But I can't see how to print entity reference values.

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('my_entity', $entity);
print $wrapper->field_my_field->value();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access entity reference values by calling entity metadata wrapper API on the reference field.

For instance, if you have a node with a field which references a `profile2` entity,

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', node_load(1));
$profile_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('profile2', $wrapper->field_profile->value());
print $profile_wrapper->field_about->value();
```

or if you prefer rendering the entity,

```
print render($profile_wrapper->view());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access entity reference values without creating a new wrapper. Entity metadata wrappers can be chained easily.

If a field is a reference field or a taxonomy term etc, the value will be the ID of the referenced entity. If you want to get the title/name of the entity, you can use the `label()` method.

A sample code:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('my_entity', $entity_id);
// To print the title/name of the referenced entity
print $wrapper->field_my_reference_field->label(); 
// To print the value of a field on the referenced entity
print $wrapper->field_my_reference_field->field_on_referenced_entity->value();
```